Significance testing for a change in rate of events in survival analysis with R
I have data examining rates of an event following a particular procedure among different sampled individuals. I expect that within X days of the procedure, the rates of my event will increase and then, after X days, return to baseline. My goal in this test is to see if there is an overall change in trend.
I would like to do a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with a uniform rate. I tried to do this in R and receive d an error saying, "Ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test." My data has ties as multiple people can have the event occur on the same post-procedure day.
Here is an example of my data and my method.
days <- c(1,2,4,4,5,6,12,16,16,17,19,21)
ks.test(days, "punif", min = 0, max = 21)

Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  days
D = 0.31429, p-value = 0.1033
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test.default(days, "punif", min = 0, max = 21) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test


Although there are (understandably) votes to close based on this being a programming question, it's not just code but raw data and R output provided as well. Moreover there is a clear statistical issue here: how worried do you need to be about the "ties should not be present for the K-S test" warning, and whether K-S is even the most appropriate test for the situation. So I voted to leave open, and even if this were to be closed I think it could be edited to be reopened with just a little work to focus on the statistical aspect.

It's close to being closable as a duplicate of Kolmogorov-Smirov two sample test, ties -- will adding random noise fix the problem? but that and its answers are for a 2-sample test and this is 1-sample. I'm not sure if there is a 1-sample question already on this topic. But there is also the possibility of using a test other than K-S: quite a lot of information about the specific context has been provided here, maybe enough to give a sensible answer about alternatives.

Happy to provide more information. I've come across two potential solutions that I haven't been able to act upon yet. There is a discrete KS test (http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/EmersonMaterials/DiscreteGOF.pdf). There is also potentially a way to do this with a parametric method through chi-squared.  Happy to hear advice from others on this situation.
